# Armadillo: Inefficient chaining of .t()

Tags: c++, performance, profiling, armadillo, blas

consider the following two ways of doing the same thing.

```
arma::Mat<double> B(5000,5000,arma::fill::randu);
arma::Mat<double> C(5000,500, arma::fill::randu);
```

Okay two dense matrices in memory. Now I want to multiply them to a new matrix, but with B transposed. Method 1:

```
arma::Mat<double> A = B.t() * C;
```

Method 2:

```
arma::Mat<double> Bt = B.t()
arma::Mat<double> A = Bt * C;
```

Which one is faster? Method 2! By a factor of about 2.5x!
Now if we allocate A before we do the multiplication, it doesn't change the time for method 2. It speeds up Method 1, but it is still 2x as slow as Method 2.

This seems bizarre to me, since I would have thought if there was no templating stuff going on at compile time that the machine code would be almost identical. So why would they have templated it in such a way that actually made it worse? Or am I missing something major?

Storing B.t() in memory as Bt and doing arma::inplace_trans(B) are about equally expensive from a time perspective. Obviously Bt = B.t() takes more memory, but you have the advantage of keeping both. I made B square so the number of multiplications is the same as A = B * C.

`A = B * C`              --> 6.98 seconds

`Bt = B.t(); A = Bt * C` --> 7.02 seconds

`A = B.t() * C`          --> 18.6124 seconds, or 14.56 seconds when A is pre-allocated (??)

I went down this rabbit-hole to see how I should store B to be more efficient, as I can construct it the other way. Especially once I start extracting rows or columns. But the difference between extracting a row and a column is actually unobservable at this scale! To be clear:
`A = B.rows(0, 499) * C`  is much faster than `A = B.cols(0, 499).t() * C`. I know they aren't the same mathematically, but if I had constructed B the other way round I was hoping for some performance benefit by accessing contiguous blocks of memory. Even `A = B.rows(0,499)` and `A = B.cols(0, 499)` are almost identical in terms of cost, which came as a surprise to me, but the scope of the question is starting to get too big.

PS: I am using OpenBLAS

Comment: I think armadillo use a very very inefficient code or our machine is very very slow (certainly not so much). Indeed, I tried a simple matrix multiplication of `B.T@C` in Numpy (Python library which uses OpenBLAS by default) and it took 140 ms on my 6-core i5-9600KF processor. This is 50 time faster! There is no reason for the transpose version to be faster here: OpenBLAS should be able to generate a fast code in both cases. In fact, `B @ C` in Numpy also take 140 ms on my machine. Did you enabled compiler optimization? Maybe Armadillo use a fallback very slow code for some strange reason...

Comment: @JérômeRichard
Thanks for the note, made me dig deeper and find the answer. Are you using parallel BLAS? When I ran in serial on a Intel Xeon Gold 6148 2.4 GHz it took around 0.4 - 0.6 seconds, it seemed to vary a fair bit. This is a debug node on a supercomputer.

Comment: I use a parallel BLAS (OpenBLAS) and it does use all the cores of my machine. The Xeon Gold 6148 as two AVX-512 units while I just have 1 AVX-2 unit AFAIK so it makes the computation much faster in sequential on the Xeon but it works at a significantly lower frequency than mine though so the results are not so surprising for a code running on 1 core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all I'm going to answer my own question here might be useful to others. The answer for me is that it was because I was using a generic OpenBLAS, not an Intel processor-specific version of BLAS, and running in debug mode.

With optimization at compile time and using an Intel processor-specific version of BLAS:

1. `Bt = B.t()` and then `A = Bt * C` is definitely slower than `A = B.t() * C`, as we would expect due to the storing of the intermediate step.
2. `A = B.t() * C` is faster than `A = B * C`, if B is square (I know this isn't the same number), but the difference is small, maybe 0-20% for the numbers I am using.
3. Along a similar line, `A = B.rows(0, 499) * C` is slower than `A = B.cols(0, 499).t() * C`.

The explanation is I believe that column access is faster than row access. `B.t() * C` uses columns of both B and C, whereas B * C uses rows of B and columns of C.

All of this is much faster than loops. So use BLAS over C++ manual loops -- this is way more important than worrying about rows vs columns.

One anomaly: `A = B.rows(0, 499)` is still faster than `A = B.cols(0, 499)`. Any ideas on why would be appreciated!

P.S. also tips on handing tensors higher than 2D in C++ would be appreciated. I hate arma::Cubes although I do use them.

Comment: It makes sense. Note that the cost of the transposition (memory-bound) should be negligible for significantly bigger matrices and much more visible for smaller ones. Note that BLAS succeed to overlap the transposition with computation and this is why it is faster to do the two operation at once. Besides this, AFAIK, Armadillo stores the matrices in a FORTRAN-like way from the past question I saw on S.O. which is a bit surprising (to check). It may explain why you get the "anomaly" between `B.rows` and `B.cols`. Note that a clever implementation can copy the row/column.